# How does Java resolve file pathname when the project is compiled?

Tags: java, javacompiler

In my source code, I created a Java File object pointing to a static image file with the pathname `src/a/b/c/img.jpeg`. When the project is built, I did not see the static image file included in the build directory. When I execute the program - how does the pathname still get resolved? I assume the correct pathname will be pointing to `build/a/b/c/img.jpeg` but the static image file is not found in the build directory. In addition, does the pathname somehow get converted from `src/a/b/c/img.jpeg` to `build/a/b/c/img.jpeg` during compilation? Since the file path should be different when it is compiled. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here?

Comment: You can get it as a system resource: ggetClass().getSystemResource(String name).

Comment: More specifically:  `SomeClassInCPackage.class.getResource("img.jpeg")` returns a URL that can be passed to ImageIO.read or to an ImageIcon constructor.  The URL’s string form can be passed to a JavaFX Image constructor.